# Bootstrap Validator.js and the Cancel button

Tags: asp.net, bootstrapvalidator

Trying out bootstrap validator (http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/), and it's pretty slick, except I don't see how to have it ignore the validation if you hit the "Cancel" button. I tried CausesValidation="false" on the Cancel button, but validation fires anyway. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Change cancel button type from `submit` to `button`

If Button Type `type="submit"` [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/u68u4vkk/)

If Button Type `type="button"` [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/u68u4vkk/1/)

[Reference](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/104) on github